# IE 11 - parent -> popup `postMessage` fails sometimes

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, window.open, postmessage

1. Open popup via `window.open`.
2. Popup `postMessage`s parent (always succeeds).
3. On popup message event, parent `postMessage`s popup (sometimes succeeds).

What could be causing inconsistent results? Works every time in Chrome.